# Use Gitlab's CI/CD with submodules - cannot run ssh

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a two private repositories: MyProject, MyProjetUtils.

My project uses the MyProjectUtils as a submodule.

My .gitsubmodules looks like this:

```
[submodule "MyProjetUtils"]
    path = MyProjetUtils
    url = git@gitlab.com:MyCompany/MyProjetUtils.git
```

My .gitlab-ci.yml file looks like this:

```
default:
  image: python:latest
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
all_test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - apt-get update
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
    - python tests/run_tests.py
```

The error I'm getting during the job run:

```
Updating/initializing submodules recursively with git depth set to 50...
Submodule 'MyProjetUtils' (git@gitlab.com:MyCompany/MyProjetUtils.git) registered for path 'MyProjetUtils'
Cloning into '/builds/MyCompany/MyProject/MyProjetUtils'...
error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
fatal: clone of 'git@gitlab.com:MyCompany/MyProjetUtils.git' into submodule path '/builds/MyCompany/MyProject/MyProjetUtils' failed
Failed to clone 'MyProjetUtils'. Retry scheduled
```

This error occur before the test stage. I've looked for answer [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/git_submodules.html), and [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#git-submodule-strategy) but could not find an answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The [first link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/git_submodules.html) you posted has the solution you are looking for:

> When your submodule is on the same GitLab server, you should use relative URLs in your .gitmodules file. Then you can clone with HTTPS in all your CI/CD jobs. You can also use SSH for all your local checkouts.

Assuming that your submodules are in the same group, update your `.gitmodules` to use a relative URL.

ie:

```
[submodule "MyProjetUtils"]
    path = MyProjetUtils
    url = ../../MyCompany/MyProjetUtils.git
```

May need to update `../../` to work for your groups.

Comment: Thanks! To setup — I've put it like URL/projectname.git and then replaced it with ../../projectname.git

Answer (score 7):

In addition to [@Rekovni's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4047472/rekovni) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68303097), you may also need to enable Token Access in the sub-module's Project configuration:

```
Settings > CI/CD Settings > Token Access
```

Ensure "Allow access to this project with a CI_JOB_TOKEN" is enabled, and add your parent project's path to the field below "Allow CI job tokens from the following projects to access this project" and click "Add project".

This will ensure that your parent project has permission to clone the sub-module repository.

Answer (score 2):

Probably very late to the party. I had the same issue that [Danil mentions in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77110867/23101106). I also use SSH locally in my proyects, and the relative URLs don't work for me. It's possible that this solution was not available back then, but I'll leave it here, in case anyone like me finds this thread.

What I did is first enable the Token Access like [davidA mentions in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76520335/23101106). And then enable the pipeline to grab submodules with `GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive` and `GIT_SUBMODULE_FORCE_HTTPS: "true"`, the latter option being what enables this trick. GitLab Reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/git_submodules.html

Hopefully it helps someone.

Comment: Thank you. THis is the key for me

variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
  GIT_SUBMODULE_FORCE_HTTPS: "true"

Answer (score 0):

There is another way.
I use ssh in my projects, so it's not convenient for me to have an https path for submodules. Also I don't think using relative paths is a good idea. Besides, all these ../../../, etc. look terrible and incomprehensible.

I solved the problem as follows.

1. Generate a pair of ssh keys.
2. Add the public key to the gitlab server.
3. Place the private key in the /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh folder.
4. Also in this folder there should be a known_hosts file, without this for some reason Gitlab ci will give a submodule authorization error.
5. Change the owner of the copied id_rsa and known_hosts files to gitlab-runner.

I created known_hosts by simply cloning the desired project manually, and copied the file under the gitlab-runner user.

I added submodules like this:

```
[submodule "libs/MySubmodule"]
path = libraries/MySubmodule
URL = ssh://git@gitlab.com:/somepath/mysubmodule.git
```

After this, gitlab-ci started working correctly.
Please note that I use my own gitlab server, so I don't know if this will work on gitlab.com.

So you have several ways to solve this problem, you must choose the one that suits you best. They all have disadvantages that you have to accept.